# BootsFaces for JSF Application

Tags: java, netbeans, bootsfaces

I'm trying to develop a jsf web application using BootsFaces in netbeans.

My problem is BootsFaces works only on the `index.xhtml` file but not on
other pages.

I've read a lot of the tutorial already but I can't seem to find an answer.

Here is my index.xhtml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"     
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <title>Facelet</title>     
</h:head>
<h:body>    
    <b:container>
    <b:navBar brand="Aim" brandHref="index" inverse="true">
            <b:navbarLinks>
                <b:navLink value="HOME" href="index.xhtml"></b:navLink>
                <b:navLink value="SHOP" href="product.xhtml"></b:navLink> 
                <b:navLink value="JOIN US" href="#"></b:navLink>
                <b:navLink value="TESTIMONIALS" href="#"></b:navLink>  
                <b:navLink value="BLOG" href="#"></b:navLink>         
            </b:navbarLinks>

            <b:navbarLinks pull="right">
                <b:dropMenu value="REGISTER">
                    <b:navLink value="AS DISTRIBUTOR" href="#"></b:navLink>
                    <b:navLink value="AS CUSTOMER" href="#"></b:navLink>            
                </b:dropMenu>       
                    <b:navLink value="LOGIN" href="#"></b:navLink> 
                    <b:navLink value="CART" href="#"></b:navLink>
            </b:navbarLinks>   
        </b:navBar>   
    </b:container>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and this is my product.xhtml page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"     
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <title>Product</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>    

    <b:navBar brand="AimTrueWealth" brandHref="index" inverse="true">
            <b:navbarLinks>
                <b:navLink value="HOME" href="index.xhtml">

                </b:navLink>
                <b:navLink value="SHOP" href="product.xhtml">

                </b:navLink> 
                <b:navLink value="JOIN US" href="#"></b:navLink>
                <b:navLink value="TESTIMONIALS" href="#"></b:navLink>  
                <b:navLink value="BLOG" href="#"></b:navLink>         
            </b:navbarLinks>

            <b:navbarLinks pull="right">
                <b:dropMenu value="REGISTER">
                    <b:navLink value="AS DISTRIBUTOR" href="#"></b:navLink>
                    <b:navLink value="AS CUSTOMER" href="#"></b:navLink>            
                </b:dropMenu>       
                    <b:navLink value="LOGIN" href="#"></b:navLink> 
                    <b:navLink value="CART" href="#"></b:navLink>
            </b:navbarLinks>   
        </b:navBar>   

</h:body>
</html>
```

Actually the codes on both pages are just the same but the problem is the b:navbar is not working on the product.xhtml page.

I hope someone could help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Jpabs

Comment: could you provide some snippets of your code, so that you can get help more easily.

Comment: Hi AdrieanKhisbe thank you for your support.

Comment: I just edited my post in order to include my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both pages are displayed without problems, at least on my machine. I suppose your problem is slightly different. The `product.xhtml` isn't displayed after navigating there from the `index.xhtml` page. You can fix this by navigating to `product.jsf` instead:

```
            <b:navLink value="HOME" href="index.jsf"></b:navLink>
            <b:navLink value="SHOP" href="product.jsf"></b:navLink>
```

If you're following the default configuration, JSF pages are linked to URLs ending with `.jsf`. You can still navigate to the `product.xhtml`, but in this case the source code is shown. Your browser tries to interpret the page as an XML page, which often results in a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using action attribute in bootsfaces 0.7.0 and I created a managed bean that returns the pages.

Thanks,

jPabs

Comment: In BootsFaces 0.8+ you'd also have to replace the `<b:navLink>` by `<b:navCommandLink>` and put the entire `b:navBar` in a `<h:form>`. The original `<b:navLink>` doesn't support actions and actionListeners.